# Regex for decimal within 0.21 to 1 range

Tags: regex, range

I am trying to create a reg exp. that falls in 0.21 to 1 range I ended doing something like

```
'^(?:1(?:\.0)?|0?\.[21-9]{2,2})$'
```

The above seems to be working but not sure if it survives all the cases, moreover the expression seems to be a bit long. Is there a way to minimize it.

Comment: `[21-9]` = `[1-9]`. To create such regexps, if you really have to, use the [generators](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) and enhance if necessary. So, a range from `21` to `99` can be matched with `(?:2[1-9]|[3-9][0-9])`, replace your `[21-9]{2,2}` with it.

Comment: What I came up with: `^(?:1(?:\.0)?|0?\.(?:[2-9][0-9]?))$`

Comment: @jingx 0.2 is also considered as valid. Can you check [that](https://regexr.com/4n21u) plz .

Comment: ^(0\.([3-9]|2[1-9])\d*|1)$

Comment: `^(?:1(?:\.0+)?|0*\.(?:2[1-9]|[3-9][0-9])0*)$` would probably work